# Wikipedia List Scrapping of Multiple Lists

Tags: google-sheets, wikipedia

I am trying to scrap a list using the formula below, but somehow, after 2,3, and I get the following error on the Google Sheet.
`"a Formula Wrong number of arguments to IMPORTHTML. Expected between 2 and 4 arguments, but got 5 arguments.`

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Danish_actors
=IMPORTHTML(J1,"list" ,2,3) < this one works
=IMPORTHTML(J1,"list" ,2,3,4,5,6,7) < generates error
```

The goal is to get the data for all the Actors from A to Z. Any advice, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ImportHTML function can have a maximum of 4 parameters, which is why your first formula seemed to work. Try doing something like this:

```
={
IMPORTHTML(J1,"list" ,2);
IMPORTHTML(J1,"list" ,3);
IMPORTHTML(J1,"list" ,4)
}
```

You can go up to list 23.

You could also do a simple copy / paste, this way you would get other interesting links like:
[image]